# Json php parsing zomato

Tags: php, arrays, json, zomato-api

I am using zomato api to get a json output which is working via php however I want to print out few arrays out of all the data that I am getting and I am having difficulty with that. Can some one help please. This is the output I am getting

```
Array
(
    [R] => Array
        (
            [res_id] => 18559961
        )

    [apikey] => 123
    [id] => 18559961
    [name] => Between Buns
    [url] => https://www.zomato.com/ncr/between-buns-sda-new-delhi?utm_source=api_basic_user&utm_medium=api&utm_campaign=v2.1
    [location] => Array
        (
            [address] => C13, SDA Market, Opposite IIT Delhi, SDA, New Delhi
            [locality] => SDA Market, SDA
            [city] => New Delhi
            [city_id] => 1
            [latitude] => 28.5465059222
            [longitude] => 77.1969081089
            [zipcode] => 
            [country_id] => 1
            [locality_verbose] => SDA Market, SDA, New Delhi
        )

    [switch_to_order_menu] => 0
    [cuisines] => Burger, American, Desserts, Sandwich, Salad, European
    [average_cost_for_two] => 1500
    [price_range] => 3
    [currency] => Rs.
    [offers] => Array
        (
        )

    [opentable_support] => 0
    [is_zomato_book_res] => 0
    [mezzo_provider] => OTHER
    [is_book_form_web_view] => 0
    [book_form_web_view_url] => 
    [book_again_url] => 
    [thumb] => https://b.zmtcdn.com/data/pictures/chains/1/18559961/c0e491e63d2e95c0c3049de0e8bbb05c.jpg?fit=around%7C200%3A200&crop=200%3A200%3B%2A%2C%2A
    [user_rating] => Array
        (
            [aggregate_rating] => 4.0
            [rating_text] => Very Good
            [rating_color] => 5BA829
            [votes] => 723
        )

    [photos_url] => https://www.zomato.com/ncr/between-buns-sda-new-delhi/photos?utm_source=api_basic_user&utm_medium=api&utm_campaign=v2.1#tabtop
    [menu_url] => https://www.zomato.com/ncr/between-buns-sda-new-delhi/menu?utm_source=api_basic_user&utm_medium=api&utm_campaign=v2.1&openSwipeBox=menu&showMinimal=1#tabtop
    [featured_image] => https://b.zmtcdn.com/data/pictures/chains/1/18559961/c0e491e63d2e95c0c3049de0e8bbb05c.jpg?output-format=webp
    [medio_provider] => 1
    [has_online_delivery] => 0
    [is_delivering_now] => 0
    [include_bogo_offers] => 1
    [deeplink] => zomato://restaurant/18559961
    [is_table_reservation_supported] => 1
    [has_table_booking] => 1
    [book_url] => https://www.zomato.com/ncr/between-buns-sda-new-delhi/book?utm_source=api_basic_user&utm_medium=api&utm_campaign=v2.1
    [events_url] => https://www.zomato.com/ncr/between-buns-sda-new-delhi/events#tabtop?utm_source=api_basic_user&utm_medium=api&utm_campaign=v2.1
)
```

and this is my code

```
<?php 

// Errors on
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// Get cURL resource
$curl = curl_init();

// Curl options
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => ['Accept: application/json', 'user-key: 123'],
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://developers.zomato.com/api/v2.1/restaurant?res_id=123',
));

// Send the request & save response to $resp
$resp = curl_exec($curl);

// Check for errors if curl_exec fails
if(!curl_exec($curl)){
    die('Error: "' . curl_error($curl) . '" - Code: ' . curl_errno($curl));
}

// Close request to clear up some resources
curl_close($curl);

// dumping $resp
//echo 'var_dump: <br>';
//var_dump($resp);
//echo '<br><br>';

// Decode json
$jsonZomato = json_decode($resp,true);

// print readable results
print "<pre>";
print_r($jsonZomato);
print "</pre>";
print $jsonZomato->aggregate_rating;//this is the problem

?>
```

The error I am getting is Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/betweenbuns/public_html/rating_2.php on line 45

Comment: You converted the object to an array because you used the `true` option in the `json_decode($resp,true)` and you are missing a level

Comment: perhaps your $jsonZomato is null. I would recomend you to check it first before print / echo data. You can try this code `print (is_null($jsonZomato) ? 'No data' : $jsonZomato->aggregate_rating);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass 2nd argument `true` in `json_decode()` function, it returns array.
As you have done in this line:

```
// Decode json
$jsonZomato = json_decode($resp,true);
```

So, Access it with keys as its an array:

```
print $jsonZomato['user_rating']['aggregate_rating'];//This should work
```